# jquery html callback

Tags: jquery, html, callback

Is there a callback for the html() function or a way to check that it is finished. For example:

```
$("#some_div").html('something here');

if($("#some_div").html() == ''){
//do something here
}
```

I am setting the html of an element from a post. Sometimes it doesnt load so when it doesnt load I would like for it to do something, is this possible. The way I have it now it always does the other thing because it hasnt set the html by the time it checks that it has html.

Comment: There shouldn't even be a race condition here. Do you have more code you can show so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: a race condition? The code is alot more complex than that but all this basically does is set the html from a post callback to the success event. so $.ajax({ success:function(){ //set the html here } }); however sometimes it fails to show the html so I just want to make it run the function again to show it, but I am going to limit it to trying only 3 times and if it fails then they are sol lol

Comment: After adding html with .html(), the DOM is not updated synchronously and that is why you can't call on the item in the same code execution.

Comment: Here's an example of the problem and a workflow around it.
To see this run this code:
$("#some_div").html('<div id="newDiv"/>');
console.log($("#newDiv").length);

The length will be 0 because the element does not exist yet.

So, use an interval as your callback:
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
     if ($("#newDiv").length){
          clearInterval(myInterval);
          MY_FUNCTION();       
     }
},10);//run it every 10ms

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`html()` is a synchronous operation. The actual updating of the DOM depends on what your html content is. If you have `<img>` or `<iframe>` tags, they will take time to load. The next statement following the `html()` should immediately see the new html contents.

Did you mean `load()` instead?

**[Edit]** Based on your comment, it is probably your `$.ajax` failing. Not `html()`. Try attaching a failure handler to ajax call and retry from there? Although, if your server side code silently fails with a 200 code, the failure event doesn't get called. In that case, you can validate the html value before you set it to the element.

Comment: +1. Judging by ngreenwood6's comment on his own question, the ajax call is the problem.

Comment: there is no problem with the ajax call. it works perfectly fine I am watching it in firebug. just sometimes it completes and shows me the data in firebug but the data is not there. No I am no using load. I am posting to a php page which is then calling my database class that is then returning data from the database to the user.

Comment: BipedalShark I dont think you know what you are talking about...You were trying to get me to use an infinite loop and you removed your post.

Comment: In my defense, I did immediately state it was a cheap hack. I deleted it because the premise of your question is fishy. As Chetan Sastry points out, the html() method is synchronous. There's no need for a callback.

Comment: as I said the ajax is not failing. I added an error event to it and it never executed. Also when I look at the response in firebug it has the information.

Answer (score 6):

**Chetan Sastry's answer(the highest answer now) is not 100% correct.**

```
$('#some_div').html('<div id="new_div">some content</div>'); // code 1    
$('#new_div').click(function(){ }); //code 2
```

I don't know why, but **in some cases, code 2 will be executed before code 1 finishing.** There is a short time less than 0 millisecond between code 1 and code 2. It should be some special executing orders in Javascript.

You have to use **cballou's way(the floor answer =_=!)** to solve the problem. e.g.

```
var sync = function(fn, millisec){
    var m = millisec ? millisec : 0; //in face, 0 is enough
    return setTimeout(fn,m);
};

$('#some_div').html('<div id="new_div">some content</div>'); // code 1    
var code2 = function(){
    $('#new_div').click(function(){ }); // run code 2, here
};

sync(code2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way i found with live and callback,

```
$('p').live('click', function() {
    // delay dont work with html() // fcallback function
    $(this).parent('div').slideUp('slow', function() {
      // empty block
      $(this).html('');
       if($(this).html()==''){
         // function
         myFunction();
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Hopefully somebody has a better solution than myself.  A quick workaround is to use setTimeout() to delay your next calls, giving your HTML block enough time to load (since the load time is so miniscule).

```
$('#some_div').html('<div>some content</div>');
// set timeout for 250 milliseconds
setTimeout(callbackFunction, 250);

function callbackFunction() {
    // do some cool sh*t
}
```

Note, however, that if you wanted to pass any variables to your function, you could do the following:

```
$('#some_div').html('<div>some content</div>');
// set timeout for 250 milliseconds
var myParam = 'value';
setTimeout(function() { callbackFunction(myParam); }, 250);

function callbackFunction(myParam) {
    // do some cool sh*t
    alert(myParam);
}
```

Comment: That wouldnt really work because if the post takes longer than the timeout that I set it will fail, but thanks for the help.

Comment: You should be setting the html within the POST callback.  An ajax request was not in your initial question.

Comment: This is bad practice, because its not dynamically.

Comment: Yeah this IS actually a solution, i ran into the same issue where a function after append and html was getting run even though it was after. I had to do a millisecond timeout on the function. It obv isnt perfect but it will at least stop the second line after the inserting of html from running right away.