# wait for dynamic DOM update before further processing

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I have some code for a CMS that allows a user to author content.  I want to show a preview for text typed in a corresponding textarea (much like here in stakeoverflow).  When the page is first loaded, the textarea is already populated and JavaScript is used to update the preview.  Once the DOM for the preview section is fully updated, further post-processing is performed on the preview section.

I found the question [jQuery/Javascript - How to wait for manipulated DOM to update before proceeding with function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342084/jquery-javascipt-how-to-wait-for-manipulated-dom-to-update-before-proceeding-w) of interest, but it's answer relies on setTimeout() which I have found somewhat problematic in the past since it's not clear how many seconds to pause before execution.

About 50% of the time, my post-processing fired prematurely because the DOM hadn't finished updating.  To fix the problem, I have tried using jQuery's Callbacks queue mechanism.

What is the best way to ensure that the dynamically modified DOM is loaded first before post-processing should start?

E.g.,

```
// using the provided source content, update the DOM indicated by
// the destination css selector string
function updatePreview(cssSelectorDst, content){
  $(cssSelectorDst).html(content);
  console.log("preview updated");
}

// if a <ul> appears at the beginning of the content, designate it
// as a keypoints section
function updateKeypoints(cssSelectorDst){
  ...
  console.log("keypoints updated");
}

// update preview section using content from iframe (using tinyMCE)
function updateFromIframe(iframeSelector, cssSelectorSrc, cssSelectorDst){

  // gather source data
  var iframe = $(iframeSelector);
  var content = $(iframe).contents().find(cssSelectorSrc).html();

  // set up callbacks to ensure proper order and completion of actions
  var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
  callbacks.add(updatePreview);
  callbacks.add(updateKeypoints);
  callbacks.fire(cssSelectorDst, content);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.html` is synchronous, code after it will not begin to execute until it is done appending html.

There is no need for using `$.Callbacks()` or any queuing system here.

```
// Update Preview
updatePreview();
updateKeypoints();
```

If you find that doesn't work, it's not because `.html()` isn't done yet, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the clarification on html() being synchronous.  That's good to know!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Kevin B, the problem was that the call to html() doesn't always have data when this method is called.  Eventually, it does, so polling is set up (yes, using setTimeout()); thank goodness for blocks (rather, anonymous functions) or this would not nearly be so elegant.

```
function updateFromIframe(iframeSelector, cssSelectorSrc, cssSelectorDst){
  var iframe = $(iframeSelector);
  var content = $(iframe).contents().find(cssSelectorSrc).html();

  if(content == null){
    console.log("content not yet available; trying again...");
    return setTimeout(function(){updateFromIframe(iframeSelector, cssSelectorSrc, cssSelectorDst)}, 50);
  }

  updatePreview(cssSelectorDst, content);
  updateKeypoints(cssSelectorDst, content);
}
```

Checking the browser console, we see that it handles this circumstance just fine.  Never mind the fact that the polling shouldn't be required in the first place!

```
content not yet available; trying again...
content not yet available; trying again...
content not yet available; trying again...
content not yet available; trying again...
content not yet available; trying again...

content: <ul><li>condimentum rhon ... nunc, <br><br></p>
preview updated

keypoints updated
```