# why the loading sign doesn't appear when i running the code on chrome "works on firefox"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had a function to fill google maps in my html page and I call function

```
popUpLoadingScreen()
{
    $("#mapLoadingUIId").css("display","block");
}

function dismissLoadingScreen()
{
    $("#mapLoadingUIId").css("display", "none");
}
```

to show loading message while the markers rendered on the map but it didn't appear, and when I put a break point to know what's the problem the sign appears but in the normal run it doesn't appear so I what to know where is the problem?

the HTML part:

```
<div id="mapLoadingUIId" class="mapLoadingUI">
    Loading...
</div>
<div id="map" class="mapBody"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyASTMSvPns7Zclg5dAGYTMQgtwia5nQy0M&callback=initMap"></script>
```

The css part:

```
.mapLoadingUI {
display:none;
position: fixed;
left: 324px;
top: 48px;
min-width: 1500px;
min-height: 100px;
z-index: 9999;
background-color:#87cefa;
z-index:1000;
text-align:center;
line-height: 100px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
font-style: normal;
font-stretch: normal;
}
```

The js that call the functions:

```
function renderWells(wells) {
    popUpLoadingScreen();
    //some code to run
    dismissLoadingScreen();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DOM refresh on long running function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876394/dom-refresh-on-long-running-function)

Comment: Use event listeners? Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876394/dom-refresh-on-long-running-function

Comment: after your comment i tried my page on firefox and the loading screen appears there but not on chrome

Answer (score 0):

Probably the code runs too fast and you are not able to see the message (It explains why you are still able to see it by putting a breakpoint). Consider also that the map rendering could be asynchronous and `renderWells` execution is completed before the actual map loading.

Take a look to the gmaps events documentation and check the available events you can handle in order to figure out when the loading is complete.

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Answer (score 0):

The dismissLoadingScreen() method is probably being called much before you intend it. Check you code for which stage are you dismissing the loader. I think its too early.

Comment: no it not, i checked that, the loading screen appears on firefox

Comment: The code in between popup and dismiss methods that you are running is  asynchronous I assume. And if it is so then you need to write the dismiss method inside the callback of the async function.