# Continue execution only after DOM manipulation has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
document.getElementById('my_id').innerHTML = 'A message';
// Next should only be executed once DOM manipulation has completed
.. do some stuff
```

I've seen this [jQuery/Javascript - How to wait for manipulated DOM to update before proceeding with function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342084/jquery-javascript-how-to-wait-for-manipulated-dom-to-update-before-proceeding), which suggests using a setTimeOut.

```
document.getElementById('my_id').innerHTML = 'A message';
setTimeout(function(){
     .. do some stuff 
},10);
```

However, this is a race, which I don't like. I need to be sure and also don't want to waste time waiting. One of the comments stated that even 0ms works because it puts it in a queue and is guaranteed to only execute after the DOM manipulation has completed. Is that absolutely certain? If so, where is this state or tested?

(The manipulation can be more complicated than this example, of course. The inserted HTML may even contain its own javascript that executes. The inserted JS execution does not have to be completed, but the rendering must have been completed.)

Comment: If it's only about detection of the rendering phase, just listen for proper events.

Comment: What event? This is not the initial loading, but DOM manipulation via JS.

Comment: please read my answer: when you modify the DOM (add node, delete node, ...) some events are fired. Just look for yours and listen to it :-)

Comment: hi, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Did you try `setTimeout(…, 0)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use both the legacy [Web events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) or the newer [Mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Each time you manipulate the DOM some events are triggered, not just the loading one.

In this example you are inserting HTML, so you need to listen to [DOMNodeInserted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) event at least.

Comment: Linking to a big long webpage with tons of events isn't really answering the question.

Comment: I'm inserting a big chunk of HTML (as a string) into another element.

Comment: just one doubt: your are inserting a _string_, right? But as a child tree or just as an attribute of that element?

Comment: The link says it is deprecated. I'm doing (jquery): $("#my_id").html("<div>more html</div>");

Comment: as I said, I would suggest you to use the Mutation observer instead of web events. Just giving you both the option I know we have.

Answer (score 1):

You should trigger the other event from the event listeners on the other actions. Basically you can have something like this

```
$(".button").click(function(){
// perform your actuibs and do some interesting stuffs
$(".anotherButton").click()
})

$(".anotherButton").click(function(){
// the other actions that needs to be performed after the first button clicked
})
```