# Function won't call after .html() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't get the `GrabOldMessages()` function to run after the `html()` runs. Below is my code.  Using jQuery version 1.7.2, I think I'm calling it back correctly, am I overlooking something? Please help me find my mistake. If you need me to provide anymore info, just let me know. Thank you for taking the time to help me.

```
//GRAB NEW MESSAGES
function GrabNewMessages(){
    var doIB = encodeURIComponent("GET_DATA"); 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', url: 'app/pull_data_files/inbox_NM_array.php',  dataType: "json",  data: { getInbox: doIB }, 
        success: function(inbox_NM_data) {                 
          if(inbox_NM_data[1] == 'true'){$('#inbox_NMlist_html').html(inbox_NM_data[0], function(){ GrabOldMessages(); });}
          else{alert("Didn't work");}
        }  
    }); 
return false;

}

//GRAB OLD MESSAGES
function GrabOldMessages(){

    var doIB = encodeURIComponent("GET_DATA"); 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', url: 'app/pull_data_files/inbox_OM_array.php',  dataType: "json",  data: { getInbox: doIB }, 
        success: function(inbox_OM_data) {                 
          if(inbox_OM_data[1] == 'true'){$('#inbox_OMlist_html').html(inbox_OM_data[0], function(){GoToInbox();});}
          else{alert("Didn't work");}

        }  
   }); 
return false;
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the HTML callback function.

Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300765/jquery-html-callback-function

Comment: I don't think there is a Html callback function as such. The solution in the linked post was to bind the image to the load event. The function specified in the load event will be triggered as soon as the image is loaded. However, as the documentation points out: `The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.` `load` will not work when bound to a `div` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying a second parameter in `html()` which takes either none or one.

Try using this success version instead for your first code-snippet.

```
 success: function(inbox_NM_data) {
    if (inbox_NM_data[1] == 'true') {
        $('#inbox_NMlist_html').html(inbox_NM_data[0]);
        GrabOldMessages();
    }
    else {
        alert("Didn't work");
    }
}
```

And this for the second code-snippet:

```
success: function(inbox_OM_data) {
    if (inbox_OM_data[1] == 'true') {
        $('#inbox_OMlist_html').html(inbox_OM_data[0]);
        GoToInbox();
    }
    else {
        alert("Didn't work");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) doesn't take two parameters, it takes *either* a string or a function, not both. And when it takes a function it isn't a completion callback.

To run a function after setting the html just call the function on the next line, so change:

```
success: function(inbox_NM_data) {                 
    if(inbox_NM_data[1] == 'true'){
         $('#inbox_NMlist_html').html(inbox_NM_data[0], function(){ GrabOldMessages(); });
    } else{
         alert("Didn't work");}
    }
```

To:

```
 success: function(inbox_NM_data) {                 
    if(inbox_NM_data[1] == 'true'){
         $('#inbox_NMlist_html').html(inbox_NM_data[0]);
         GrabOldMessages();
    } else{
         alert("Didn't work");}
    }
```

(And similar within your `GrabOldMessages()` function.)

Answer (score -3):

**this code is 100% work**

```
$('#myTabContent').html(data);    
afterHTML();

function afterHTML(){           
    $('.unit').change(function(){
        var u=($(this).val()).split('/');
        $('.perunit').html(u[1]);
    });    
}
```