# jQuery + CSS. How do I compute height and width of innerHTML?

Tags: jquery, css, innerhtml

I have a typical parent-child div hierarchy for a Web project using jQuery. The child css has not height, this allows it to expand and contract based on the height of the innerHTML. I am programmatically stuffing HTML markup into the innerHTML property of the child.

I want to set the height of the parent to match the height of the child after the child has it's markup. How do I do this? I tried:

```
    childDiv.innerHTML = content;
    childDivObject = $(childDiv);

     parentDivObject = $(parentDiv);
     parentDivObject.css({
        "height" : childDivObject.height() + "px"
    });
```

But this did not work. What am I missing?

### UPDATE 0

More context. This code is for a popup that appears/disappears with a user tap. Here is the css. There is just not a lot going on here:

```
// parent
.parent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 350px;
    display: none;
}

// child
.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 25px;
}
```

Could the fact that the parent has **display:none** be part of the problem? I am using the jQuery show()/hide() methods if that is relevant.

Comment: You should check height of the child on every HTML Markup is inserted into the child and then add the height to the parent
parentDiv.height(childDiv.height());

Comment: since you're using jquery, have you tried `childDiv.html(content)` ? the parent will expand with the child after html insertion without problems

Comment: Are you inserting the content in the child div upon clicking to show the parent?

Comment: jQuery is not the issue here. The issue is: why is my div reporting a height of 0 after innerHTML has be stuffed with markup and it renders properly.

Comment: The problem is with 2 elements positioned absolute.  So the child element takes no space in the parent element

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
"height" : childDivObject.height() + "px"
```

to this:

```
"height" : childDiv.height() + "px"
```

Looks like you are trying to get the height of the content rather than the div itself.

Comment: David, childDiv is the DOM element and childDivObject is just the jQuery-ified flavor of the same thing so I can use jQuery methods. When I call childDivObject.height() after setting innerHTML I am getting a height of 0. Even though the div is rendering properly. Does not setting innerHTML trigger the setting of height/width of the element? I don't get it.

Comment: Can this not just be solved by not applying any height to the parent? Perhaps a jsfiddle would help us understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use a callback, but html() doesn't have one, but there's something else, called promise.

[jquery html() callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300765/jquery-html-callback-function)
http://digitizor.com/2013/08/03/jquery-html-callback-function-using-promise/

```
   $('#divId').html(someText).promise().done(function(){
        //your callback logic / code here
    });
```

Comment: George, .html(content, function(){ // do stuff }) does not fire. .html(content).innerHeight() reports 0 height. Yet the content renders properly. None of this makes any sense.

Comment: Changed my answer. Callback doesn't work on html(), you need a promise.

Comment: promise()? You're joking right? I mean is that an actually method?

Comment: George, the root issues is that height cannot be set on an element with display:none. Oddly, and completely inconsistenly I can set top/left. It's like it is all designed to be a time sucking experience doing web development. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Because jQuery toggles the css display property to hide/show the popup.

The answer is to do this:

```
    parentDivObject.css({
        "left": left + "px",
        "top" : top  + "px"
    }).show();

    parentDivObject.css({
        "height": childDivObject.height() + "px"
    });
```

I set the height **after** the jQuery show() method which toggles display and then height becomes valid. It's not pretty, but it works. Cheers.

Comment: ye, you didn't solve the main cause of your problem, you just found a way around it.. that's some ugly-ass code :/

Comment: George, actually I think it is a bug that it is not possible to set height/width/whatever on an element if display is none. I see nothing wrong with my approach given the hair ball that is web tools.