# Rails 4 - event to run code after a partial is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partials

I have a js.erb file that is called with ajax through a controller action.  The js.erb file renders a partial.  Inside the partial is a data attribute that is generated based from the model.  I need a way to run code only after the partial is rendered because the code is using information in the data attribute.

**items_controller.rb**

```
  def remove_tag
    @item = Item.find_by_id(params[:id])
    //code to remove tag from item
    @item.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      @item.reload
    end
  end
```

**remove_tag.js.erb**

```
$("#taglist").html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "items/tag_list", locals: {item: @item}) %>');
//the code below needs to be run after the above partial is rendered
$('#add-tag').rules("add", {
  tagUniqueness: $('#taglist').data('tag-list').split(', ')
});
```

**_tag_list.html.erb**

```
<div id="taglist" data-tag-list="<%= item.all_tags_list %>">
  //more html
</div>
```

The way it is now, the .rules method is using html data that was there before the partial updates it.

Comment: Your views should simply present models. If your view is altering the model you are doing something very wrong as violates MVC badly.

Comment: My view isn't changing the model, the model is changed with the remove_tag action.

Comment: `tagUniqueness: "<%= @item.tags.pluck(:name).join(', ') %>"` - seems like a much more straight forward solution since you can just get it from rails instead of the DOM.

Comment: @max I am trying to get the right output using your suggestion.  The method I need to use on @item is .all_tags_list. (from [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on))  I am checking by using console.log in the `remove_tag.js.erb` file.  I tried `console.log ("<%= @badge.all_tags_list %>")` and it returns `tag1, tag2, tag3`.  How can I make this an array of strings?  I tried appending .split(', ') but it gave me `[[&quot;tag1&quot;, &quot;tag2&quot;, &quot;tag3&quot;]]`

Comment: Sorry I missread your JS and thought you wanted a string. You can use `.to_json` to convert a Ruby array to javascript (since valid JSON is valid javascript).

Comment: @max awesome works great.  You should have posted as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert hashes or arrays from Ruby to javascript you can use `.to_json` as JSON basically is a subset of javascript.

```
$('#add-tag').rules("add", {
  tagUniqueness: <%= js @badge.all_tags_list.to_json %>
});
```

Comment: I was using `raw` instead of `js`.  Is one better than the other?

Comment: In this case it probably does not really make a difference - I don't think you can do a XSS attack by creating a really creative tag name anyways since encoding as JSON will escape it. `raw` is likely faster since it does not use `gsub` or actually do anything to the string besides marking it as safe.

Answer (score 3):

This type of functionality would lend itself to [`callbacks`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp) in javascript/jquery...

> A callback function is executed after the current effect is 100% finished.

We used callbacks for executing functions after ajax loads (which had to remain asynchronous). They are highly effective if you can get them to work.

There's a [great reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18040133/1143732):

```
$("#taglist").html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "items/tag_list", locals: {item: @item}) %>').promise().done(function(){
    $('#add-tag').rules("add", {
       tagUniqueness: <%= js @badge.all_tags_list.to_json %>
    });
});
```