# jQuery promise().done() is not working

Tags: jquery, promise

jQuery `promise().done()` is not working. Below is my code:

```
<div id="testtesttest">gggggg</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        new Ajax.Request('testurl', {
            method: 'get',
            parameters: {
                id: param
            },
            onSuccess: function() {
                alert('success');
                jQuery('div#testtesttest').html('teststring').promise().done(function() {
                    alert('afterpromise');
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It's alerting **"success"**, replacing **"teststring"** with **"gggggg"** but not alerting **"afterpromise"**

I am using jquery-1.10.2.

Edited:
Original code

```
<?php if (!$this->getAttributeCode() || $this->getProduct()->getData($this->getAttributeCode())): ?>
    <div id="<?php echo $this->getBlockId() ?>" class="lazyblocks-loader">&nbsp;</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Event.observe(window, 'load', function(){
            new Ajax.Request('<?php echo $this->getUrl('lazyblocks/product/' . $this->getLazyAction()) ?>', {
                method: 'get',
                parameters: {
                    id: <?php echo $this->getProductId(); ?>
                },
                onSuccess: function(transport){
                    var data  = transport.responseText;
                    var block = jQuery('#<?php echo $this->getBlockId() ?>')
                    block.removeClass('lazyblocks-loader');
                    if (data.isJSON()) {
                        var jsonData = data.evalJSON();
                        if (jsonData.html) {
                            block.html(jsonData.html).promise().done(function(){
                                block.find('img.lazy').jail({
                                    id              : 'page',
                                    event           : 'load+scroll',
                                    loadHiddenImages: true,
                                    offset          : 10000
                                });
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('lazyblocks.loader.oncomplete'); ?>
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: What's this promise supposed to do ? There's no asynchronous call in it

Comment: `html()` is synchronous, it doesn't need a callback, promise or anything like that.

Comment: Why not put all of the onSuccess code in the .done?

Comment: to make updated div as part of DOM, I have to run lazy loading after promise. But don't know why promise doesn't his job and give control back to me.

Comment: .done is not working as well

Comment: Of course it's not working, there's nothing to attach a promise to, html() doesn't return a deferred.

Comment: you don't need the promise. `.html()` is synchronous.

Comment: Calling [`$().promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) on jQuery objects only works for methods that do asynchronous work, like animations. `$.html` does not return something that can be turned into a promise

Comment: @JuanMendes or Kevin or adeneo or dystroy, one of you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Guys, look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/promise/): *Using `.promise()` on a collection with no active animation returns a resolved Promise.* The questioner's code *should* work.

Comment: code in edited section is working for older version of magento, I just upgraded to EE and lazy loading is not working. When I alert something in old code after promise line it works but doesn't in EE version. Both have same jquery library

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, it will *work*, **but it won't do what he thinks it will.** and is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773875/

Comment: @murtzagondal uhh... I think it will.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum unfortunately its not working, don't know why.

Comment: @murtzagondal create a self contained example fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net illustrating the issue. Until then it's unclear, voting to close as 'debugging without a reproducable sample'

Comment: @Kevin, I did not say the opposite (mainly because I've no idea of what the questioner actually wants). However, the code in the `done` handler should run. Maybe too soon, but it still should. If it doesn't, the problem might come from somewhere else.

Comment: Why debug why a resolved promise doesn't seem to be resolved when you **don't need a promise**?

Comment: @KevinB I know... but the point is that it should work. It turns out it does work in jQUery 2.1+ See my answer

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Please see my answer and consider removing your vote to close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your version of jQuery. If you use a later version (2.1 and later), it will work. In the latest version, jQuery elements create a resolved promise if there is no asynchronous work pending. See

- http://jsfiddle.net/fHyH7/ (working with latest jQuery)
- http://jsfiddle.net/fHyH7/1/ (not working, with 1.10)

Some fake code so I can link to jsfiddle

```
// Fake code so I can link to jsfiddle
```

Comment: I believe @FrédéricHamidi is correct and my code should work but its not working :(

Comment: purpose of promise here is, I need to run lazyloading which only works on DOM elements, my ajax requests returns products data and their images have to load using jail lib but promose doesn't get passed

Comment: @murtzagondal Your comment is very hard to decipher. If you have more information, post it in your question. Post the code you are using. I already told you what the problem with your code is.

Comment: yeah I just read you updated answer, Thanks, let me update jquery, I will post if it works